# Are there any better/more efficient ways to carry out this SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently I'm using the query:

```
SELECT * from budget where CentreID = (SELECT CentreID from budget where BudgetID = "?");
```

It's working as it is, but I'm wondering if there is any way to make it more efficient or if not using joins is bad practise in this situation.

Thanks.

Comment: I sincerely doubt that a single value subquery will be slower than a JOIN. My vote is to use whichever you're more comfortable with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your query is working, I assume that your subquery returns only one row. It means that a budgetID corresponds to one and only one centerID.
If this is the case, you could use this query :

```
SELECT * from budget where BudgetID = "?";
```

If a budgetID can be assigned to multiple centerID, the your query should be something like that :

```
SELECT * from budget where CentreID IN 
(SELECT CentreID from budget where BudgetID = "?");
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Are there any pros to using these queries over the one in my original post?

Comment: The first query maybe faster since it drop the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT * from budget where CentreID IN (SELECT CentreID from budget where BudgetID = "?");
```

OR

```
SELECT a.* 
from budget as a
JOIN
(
SELECT CentreID 
from budget 
where BudgetID = "?"
) as b ON a.CentreID = b.CentreID
```

Comment: Are there any particular reasons for using each of these queries, for speed or best practise for example?